# SelectionChange to get username and date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am very new to Excel VBA and I’m an trying to write some code that achieves the following:
When a cell is clicked in column A that contained the text “123” or “xyz” the cell in the same row but in column B records the current time, and the cell in the same row but in column C records the username of the person who clicked it.

The following is the code I am currently using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim RowNum As Long
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Value.Text = 123 Then Exit Sub
If Not Target.Value.Text = XYZ Then Exit Sub

  RowNum = Target.Row
  Range("B" & RowNum).Value = Date
  Range("C" & RowNum).Value = Environ("UserName")

End Sub
```

Currently I a variable not defined error on XYZ, however I feel as if there is quite a lot of other issues with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were not too far. I think this should work fine:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) '<-- event is change, non selection change

Dim RowNum As Long
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Column <> 1 Then Exit Sub
If (Target.Value = "123") Or (Target.Value = "xyz") Then '<-- if the value is either "xyz" or "123"

  RowNum = Target.Row
  Range("B" & RowNum).Value = Now() '<-- current time in column B
  Range("C" & RowNum).Value = Environ("UserName") '<-- username in column C

End If

End Sub
```